# OpenGL Textured Cube Not Being Mapped Correctly

Tags: c++, opengl

A couple days ago I started on a small voxel game with opengl 1.1(I know its very outdated). I use the sfml library to create an opengl context. I think the problem is with the texture coordinates, but I'm not sure. The render code:

```
    glPushMatrix();
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glColor3f(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
    //front
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex3f(0, 1, 0);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 1); glVertex3f(1, 1, 0);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex3f(1, 0, 0);
    //back
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glVertex3f(0, 0, 1);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex3f(0, 1, 1);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 1); glVertex3f(1, 1, 1);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex3f(1, 0, 1);
    glColor3f(0.6, 0.6, 0.6);
    //top
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glVertex3f(0, 1, 0);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex3f(0, 1, 1);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 1); glVertex3f(1, 1, 1);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex3f(1, 1, 0);
    //bottom
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex3f(0, 0, 1);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 1); glVertex3f(1, 0, 1);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex3f(1, 0, 0);
    glColor3f(0.7, 0.7, 0.7);
    //left
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex3f(0, 1, 0);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 1); glVertex3f(0, 1, 1);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex3f(0, 0, 1);
    //right
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glVertex3f(1, 0, 0);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex3f(1, 1, 0);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 1); glVertex3f(1, 1, 1);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex3f(1, 0, 1);
    glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();
```

This is the one of the in-game wood textures:
[image: In game texture]

This is the image of the wood texture:
[image]

It gets mapped on really weirdly. What is wrong? Can someone post an example of a normal textured cube?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing your code:

```
glTexCoord2f(0, 0); ...
glTexCoord2f(1, 0); ...
glTexCoord2f(1, 1); ...
glTexCoord2f(1, 0); ...
```

into

```
glTexCoord2f(0, 0); ...
glTexCoord2f(1, 0); ...
glTexCoord2f(1, 1); ...
glTexCoord2f(0, 1); ... (changed this line)
```

You're mapping two corners of the cube to the same point in the texture.

Comment: Oh I feel so stupid!! Why did I do that? Anyways, thank you so much! I can continue my voxel game!