# openGL - testure mapping cube fails

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I am trying something quite easy, normally: applying a texture on the different surfaces of a cube.
I am able to apply it but it seems as if he just takes an average of the colors of my image.

why please?
my code:

```
void MyGLWidget::drawCube()
{
    glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); 
    glLoadIdentity();               
//  glPushMatrix();

    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glLoadIdentity();

    glTranslatef( 0.5, 0, 0.0); 
    glRotatef(getCubeAngle(), 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); 
    glTranslatef(0, 0, 0);

    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_S);
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_T);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);

       //back
       glVertex3f(-0.1, 0.1,-0.1 );//upper left corner
       glVertex3f(0.1, 0.1,-0.1); //uper right
       glVertex3f(0.1,-0.1,-0.1 ); // down left
       glVertex3f(-0.1,-0.1,-0.1); // down right
/* other code to create rest of the cube*/

      glEnd();
      glFlush();
 //     glPopMatrix();
}

void MyGLWidget::resizeGL(int width, int height)
{
  glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  glLoadIdentity();
  glScalef(height *1./width, 1.0, 1.0);
  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}

void MyGLWidget::myTextureMapping()
{

        QImage t;
        QImage b;

        if(!b.load("..../myImage.bmp"))
        {qDebug("error with image\n");}


        t = QGLWidget::convertToGLFormat(b);
        glGenTextures( 1, &texture[0] );
        glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0] );
        glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, t.width(), t.height(), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, t.bits() );
        glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
        glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
}


void MyGLWidget::initializeGL()
{
    myTextureMapping();

        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);        
        glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);                        
        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);           
        glClearDepth(1.0f);                         
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);                
        glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);                             
        glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);  

}
```

**EDIT:**

added those tex coordinates:

```
  glTexCoord2f(-0.1, 0.1);    
  glVertex3f(-0.1, 0.1,0 );//upper left corner

  glTexCoord2f(0.1, 0.1);      
  glVertex3f(0.1, 0.1,0); //uper right

  glTexCoord2f(0.1, -0.1);
  glVertex3f(0.1,-0.1,0 ); // down left

  glTexCoord2f(-0.1, -0.1);    
  glVertex3f(-0.1,-0.1,0); // down right
```

But my image is bigger than the face of my cube:

source image : http://imgur.com/h48QARM

result in software: http://imgur.com/rxvK0Ot

Answer (score 1):

You should be providing the texture co-ordinates for each vertex. What you have right now is just a position data for the Quad, texture co-ordinates are missing.

Have a look at this :

[OpenGL Textured Cube Not Being Mapped Correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18070230/opengl-textured-cube-not-being-mapped-correctly?rq=1)

Try this :

```
glTexCoord2f(0, 0);    
glVertex3f(-0.1, 0.1,0 );//upper left corner

glTexCoord2f(1, 0);      
glVertex3f(0.1, 0.1,0); //uper right

glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
glVertex3f(-0.1,-0.1,0 ); // down left

glTexCoord2f(1, 1);    
glVertex3f(0.1,-0.1,0); // down right
```

Comment: Please read bit more on texture co-ordinates & how they work. Right now, I can say that it is happening because of wrong texture coords values. Make sure you provide correct texture coords values. Also, not sure if the vertex coords are right too in terms of left, right , top, bottom positions.

Comment: Edited the main answer, see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the texture coordinates wrong? To me it seems like you're going -0.1 to 0.1, while texture coordinates normally are defined in the interval [0,1].

Comment: indeed I understood it wrongly. Thank you! corrected it.